# create-react-app with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, create-react-app

i have created an application from create-react-app and it works well. 
When I added react-navitation I got this error:

```
./node_modules/react-navigation/src/routers/StackActions.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const pop = payload => ({
|   type: POP,
|   ...payload,
| });
|
```

It seens we don't have "transform-object-rest-spread" babel plugin. Could someone knows how may I add it?

this is my dependencies inside package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3516

> we don't explicitly support web or reactxp currently. if you'd like to submit a RFC for how we could do that and own it, it would be nice. it's not a priority right now. so this is more of a feature request than a bug. sorry :(

See also [this section](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation#can-i-use-this-library-for-web) of their docs.

TL;DR -- they ship un-transpiled code and are targeting React Native. I would suggest looking at alternatives, such as the tried-and-true [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), or a newer one from one of the original authors, [reach-router](https://github.com/reach/router).

Answer (score 1):

React Navigation has recently released a new update that supports `react-navigation` with `create-react-app`

> Starting in v3, React Navigation has built-in support for web sites, including server rendering.

See more details in their docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html).